# Incorrect texture coordinate calculated for shadow map

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-4, shadow-mapping

I am having problems getting the correct texture coordinate to sample my shadow map. Looking at my code, the problem appears to be from incorrect matrices. This is the fragment shader for the rendering pass where I do shadows:

```
in vec2 st;

uniform sampler2D colorTexture;
uniform sampler2D normalTexture;
uniform sampler2D depthTexture;
uniform sampler2D shadowmapTexture;

uniform mat4 invProj;
uniform mat4 lightProj;

uniform vec3 lightPosition;

out vec3 color;

void main () {
    vec3 clipSpaceCoords;
    clipSpaceCoords.xy = st.xy * 2.0 - 1.0;
    clipSpaceCoords.z = texture(depthTexture, st).x * 2.0 - 1.0;
    vec4 position = invProj * vec4(clipSpaceCoords,1.0);
    position.xyz /= position.w;
    //At this point, position.xyz seems to be what it should be, the world space coordinates of the pixel. I know this because it works for lighting calculations.

    vec4 lightSpace = lightProj * vec4(position.xyz,1.0);
    //This line above is where I think things go wrong.
    lightSpace.xyz /= lightSpace.w;
    lightSpace.xyz = lightSpace.xyz * 0.5 + 0.5;
    float lightDepth = texture(shadowmapTexture, lightSpace.xy).x;
    //Right here lightDepth seems to be incorrect. The only explanation I can think of for this is if there is a problem in the above calculations leading to lightSpace.xy.

    float shadowFactor = 1.0;
    if(lightSpace.z > lightDepth+0.0005) {
         shadowFactor = 0.2;
    }
    color = vec3(lightDepth);
}
```

I have removed all the code irrelevant to shadowing from this shader (Lighting, etc). This is the code I use to render the final pass:

```
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

postShader->UseShader();
postShader->SetUniform1I("colorTexture", 0);
postShader->SetUniform1I("normalTexture", 1);
postShader->SetUniform1I("depthTexture", 2);
postShader->SetUniform1I("shadowmapTexture", 3);
//glm::vec3 cp = camera->GetPosition();
postShader->SetUniform4FV("invProj", glm::inverse(camera->GetCombinedProjectionView()));
postShader->SetUniform4FV("lightProj", lights[0].camera->GetCombinedProjectionView());
//Again, if I had to guess, these two lines above would be part of the problem.
postShader->SetUniform3F("lightPosition", lights[0].x, lights[0].y, lights[0].z);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameBuffer->GetColor());
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameBuffer->GetNormals());
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameBuffer->GetDepth());
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, lights[0].shadowmap->GetDepth());

this->BindPPQuad();
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

In case it is relevant to my problem, here is how I generate the depth framebuffer attachments for the depth and shadow maps:

```
void FrameBuffer::Init(int textureWidth, int textureHeight) {
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glGenTextures(1, &depth);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, textureWidth, textureHeight, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth, 0);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

Where is the problem in my math or my code, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation, I have found that my problem does not lie in my matrices, but in my clamping. It seems that I get strange values when I use GL_CLAMP or GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, but I get almost correct values when I use GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER. There are more problems, but they do not seem to be matrix related as I thought.

Comment: I use GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, and it works fine. It sounds to me like your matrix math is incorrect. Your shadow transform should be like so:

`mat4 shadowTransform = biasMatrix * lightProj * lightView;`

the bias matrix essentially clamps the transformed world space coordinates of the fragment between 0.0 and 1.0, so they are in the correct space.

If you have no bias matrix, `mat4 shadowTransform = lightProj * lightView;` You can do this:

`vec4 shadowcoord = shadowTransform*vec4(worldcoord,1.0);` then `vec2 shadowXY = shadowCoord.xy*2.0-1.0;`
Which will achieve the same result.